# Google spread sheetのQUERYで関数が含まれるセルを表示したい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

ItemsシートのEには `=IMAGE(***)` などの関数が入っています。

```
=QUERY('Items'!D:F, "SELECT E WHERE F LIKE '%ABC%'",1)
```

とあった場合、  `=IMAGE(***)` をQUERYのセルで実行してほしいのですがセルは空欄のままとなってしまいます。
SELECT DとするとD列にある文字が問題なく表示されるので処理は間違っていないと思われますが、
QUERY関数では取得したセルの関数を実行することはできないのでしょうか？

また、同様のことを行う他の手段はありますか？

FILTERだとできそうなのですが、F列に特定の文字を含む行のE列を取得する（上記QUERY分と同じ）を行う方法がわからずです。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUERYを使った場合は、画像は表示されないようですね。こちらの[質問](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74035)を見ますと、どうやらQUERYではIMAGEは使用できないようです。そこで、別の方法として、質問内でもありますようにFILTERを使用する方法について下記に提案させていただきます。

`F列に特定の文字を含む行のE列を取得する`について、この場合、[REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=ja)を使用するのはいかがでしょうか。

```
=FILTER(Items!E2:E,REGEXMATCH(Items!F2:F,"ABC"))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！FILTERを使った場合の悩みなのですが 、
例えば  `Items!F2:F` に ABCに該当するものが複数あった場合、下の行にまで影響してしまい、下の行に
`=FILTER(Items!E2:E,REGEXMATCH(Items!F2:F,"DEF"))`
とあった場合、#REF! エラーが表示されてしまうかと思います。
このFILTERで1件だけ返してもらう。という書き方はできるのでしょうか？
REGEXMATCHならできそうな気もしますが、いまいちピンと来ておりません。。

Comment: と、書きながらちょっと調べてみたらINDEX()という関数がありましたね。
`=INDEX(FILTER(Items!E2:E,REGEXMATCH(Items!F2:F,"ABC")))`
でうまいことできそうです！この使い方結構用いる場面多いので考察の一助になり大変助かりました

Comment: @tadashi ご返事ありがとうございます。取得したデータから一つだけ選択したい場合は、仰る通り`INDEX`を使用できると思います。以前どこかで`=IMAGE(QUERY(,,))`のような使い方を見たように思ったのですが、テストをしたところ動作しませんでした。私の記憶違いかもしれません。